# Корректно ли писать имя в таком контексте?

Tags: выбор-слов

*"Он поднял **Светкины** брюки" или только "он поднял брюки **Светы**"?*

*То была **Риткина** квартира.*

*Он расстегнул верхнюю пуговицу на **Людкиной** кофте.*

Comment: Все Ваши примеры вполне подходят для менее строгого, свободного стиля изложения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все зависит от того, **кто** пишет, **о ком** пишет и **в каком жанре-стиле** пишет.
Светкины, Риткина, Людкина — это [притяжательные прилагательные](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/39-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_fonetika__slovoobrazovanie__morfologiya_i_orfografiya/stages/668-331_ponyatie_ob_imeni_prilagatelnom_morfologicheskie_priznaki_imen_prilagatelnyh_razryady_imen_prilagatelnyh.html).

Они обозначают признаки предмета по его принадлежности какому-нибудь человеку или животному.
*Отцов пиджак, мамин платок, лисий хвост, волчий след.*
Эти прилагательные отвечают на вопросы ***чей? чья? чьё? чьи?***

Стоит отметить, что ***Светкины*** брюки — это *брюки **Светки***, а не Светы (Риткина квартира — квартира Ритки; Людкина кофта — кофта Людки).

Можно сравнить просто названия: **Демьянова уха** (И. А. Крылов); **Кошкин дом** (С. Я. Маршак); **Иваново детство** (фильм); **Маруськины заметки** (Н. Каледина); **Танюшкино детство** (Т. Лозицкая); **Сенькин брод** (Д. Чепиков); **Зойкина квартира** (М. Булгаков).

*Риткину квартиру я открыла без труда хранившимся у меня ключом...

Услышав Риткин крик, доносящийся из коридора, я подумала, что...

К сожалению, окна Людкиной квартиры выходили на проспект.*
*В старом районе... в подъезде, на втором этаже – Светкина квартира.*